# You do not have permission to view this directory or page. (ASP.NET website to Azure)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have uploaded my ASP.Net site to Azure but when I try to browse I get this message:

> "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

I have nothing in my web.config file right now and I have tried to google on it and tried this code (just copied/pasted it) without any progress:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Sommarstugan">
      <match url="/*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Then it says this instead:

> "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

My startpage is called "Default.aspx" and is located in a folder called "HTML" and I have tried ti change it to index.aspx but nothing changed.

What should I do?
Tnx

Comment: Check your permissions.  On linux at least (using MONO), I have to make my pages both readable AND executable.  Mayhaps you have to do something similar on windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call hostname/HTML/Default.aspx see if that works.