# Azure: You do not have permission to access this page

Tags: asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2013

- I Have just Created an Empty ASP.NET project with AngularJS and
  Bootstrap.  (No C# or anything yet. Only HTML and JavaScript)
- I debug using IIS Express and everything works fine.
- I've signed up for an Azure account and downloaded my
  publish settings file.
- I've imported it from the Build > Publish
  "solution name" from Visual Studio 2013 I get a successful connection
  verification.
- I publish successfully.

When Visual Studio opens the webpage remotely, I get an error message saying:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Some of the things I've tried from googling:

1. [An Elmah Tutorial](http://www.xoltar.org/?p=125)
2. [I don't understand this one...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494180/you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page-asp-net-website-to-a)

Comment: Are you sure you are going to the correct URL including index.html? i.e. `http://yoursite.azurewebsites.net/app/index.html` - check the site url in Website => Dashboard => Site URL

Comment: I didnt't even think to try that....I thought it would work the same way it did in Visual Studio's debugger....thanks for that!

Comment: If you've found an answer, please provide and accept it as an answer.